# How to join/detach/clean dynamic malloc threads that are created per function call?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote a sample code of my problem. In the while loop, I am dynamically creating new threads per function call, which will be processed in the calculate function. This could potentially take several seconds to finish and I used sleep to simulate this.

How do I clean these threads? They have separate threads with their own stack of args, so would it be possible to clean them in the calculate function at the end per call? But then I would run into the problem of some threads still calculating when the condition of `random == 2` is met and the program exits.

I'm thinking of a variable that would change state when the calculation has finished, but still have the same problem as described above. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct args_struct {
    pthread_t pt;
    int random;
};

void* calculate(void *arguments){
    struct args_struct *args = arguments;
    sleep(args->random);
    printf("Number: %d. %s", args->random, "Calculations completed, thanks for waiting!");
}

int main(){
    while(1){
        struct args_struct *args = malloc(sizeof (struct args_struct));
        time_t t;
        srand((unsigned) time(&t));
        args->random = rand() % 5;

        if(pthread_create( &args->pt, NULL, calculate, (void *)&args) != 0)
            printf("Error in creating thread!");        

        if (args->random == 2 ){ //random condition in exiting loop
            printf("Number is %d. Exiting program and joining remainder threads still running...", args->random);
            //pthread_join? free(args)? pthread_exit? pthread_detach?
            //pthread_join(args->pt, NULL);
            //free(args);
            return 0;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument args of pthread_create() is wrong.
Try change (void *)&args -> (void *)args.

Default stdout stream buffering is line buffering(_IOLBF).
Try insert '\n' character to printf() function.

Create seed(srand function) only once.

Finally, try the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct args_struct {
    pthread_t pt; 
    int random;
};

void* calculate(void *arguments){
    struct args_struct *args = arguments;
    sleep(args->random);
    printf("Number: %d. %s\n", args->random, "Calculations completed, thanks for waiting!");
    if (args->random != 2) free(args);
}

int main(){
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    while(1){
        struct args_struct *args = malloc(sizeof (struct args_struct));
        args->random = rand() % 5;

        if(pthread_create( &args->pt, NULL, calculate, (void *)args) != 0)
            printf("Error in creating thread!\n");    

        if (args->random == 2 ){ //random condition in exiting loop
            printf("Number is %d. Exiting program and joining remainder threads still running...\n", args->random);
            pthread_join(args->pt, NULL);
            free(args);
            return 0;
        };  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesnt work. It doesnt wait for threads above `args->random > 2`. For example, if printed out the `args-> random`, the pthread_join does not wait for those to complete. It seems like the threads created are not all waited